# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE on line 5

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I am new to PHP and am encountering this parsing error. My code is:

```
 <?php
   $con=mysqli_connect("glcmcrusaders.ipagemysql.com", "cycregister", "Crusaders13!",          
    "registration")


    $sql="INSERT INTO camperregistration (camperFirstName, camperLastName, camperGender,       
    camperBirthdate, camperStreet, camperCity, camperState, camperZip, camperCountry,   
    camperShirtSize, guardianFirstName, guardianLastName, guardianStreet, guardianCity,  
    guardianState, guardianZip, guardianCountry, guardianCell, guardianEmail,  
    alternateFirstName, alternateLastName, alternateStreet, alternateCity, alternateState, 
    alternateZip, alternateCountry, alternateCell, alternateRelationship, camperSwimming)
    VALUES 
    ('$_POST[camperFirstName]', '$_POST[camperLastName]', '$_POST[camperGender]',     
    '$_POST[camperBirthdate]', '$_POST[camperStreet]', '$_POST[camperCity]',   
    '$_POST[camperState]', '$_POST[camperZip]', '$_POST[camperCountry]',  
    '$_POST[camperShirtSize]', '$_POST[guardianFirstName]', '$_POST[guardianLastName]', 
    '$_POST[guardianStreet]', '$_POST[guardianZip]', '$_POST[guardianCountry]', 
    '$_POST[guardianCell]', '$_POST[guardianEmail]', '$_POST[alternateFirstName]', 
    '$_POST[alternateLastName]', '$_POST[alternateStreet]', '$_POST[alternateCity]',
    '$_POST[alternateState]', '$_POST[alternateZip]', '$_POST[alternateCountry]',  
    '$_POST[alternateCell]', '$_POST[alternateRelationship]', '$_POST[camperSwimming]')";

     mysqli_close($con);
     ?>
```

Line 5 starts at the %sql ="INSERT INTO... ends at camperSwimming)
I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: FYI, you are wide open to [SQL injections](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174)

Comment: How would i change that?

Answer (score 10):

Missing a semi-colon:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("glcmcrusaders.ipagemysql.com", "cycregister", "Crusaders13!",          
"registration") // <-- HERE
```

Answer (score 1):

you need a `terminator(;)` at the end of  `$con`.

```
$con=mysqli_connect("glcmcrusaders.ipagemysql.com", "cycregister", "Crusaders13!",          
    "registration");
                   ^Here
```